# Geometrical meaning - limits

Tags: calculus

I want to find the following limit, if it exists.

$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\cos x-1-\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4+y^4}$

If we say : let $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ along the line $y=0$ , what exactly does it mean geometrically?

Also, if we want to check whether the limit $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} g(x,y) $ exists where $g(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$, we pick $y=mx$ and since $g(x,mx)$ depends on $m$ we deduce that the limit does not exist.

If $g(x,mx)$ would be independent on $m$, would that mean that the limit exists? If so, why?

**EDIT**: If $g(x,mx)$ depends on $m$, that means that the limit depends on the direction that we follow and so the limit does not exist.

If it is independent on $m$ and the limit exists, can we say that the limit is equal to the result that we have found? Or not since we pick $y$ to have a specific form?

**EDIT 2**: If we consider the limit along the line $x=0$ and the limit along the line $y=0$ and they are equal and have a value let $c$ does this mean that the original limit is equal to $c$?

Comment: Are you sure of the numerator?

Comment: Are you comparing taking the limit as $x\to0$ and $y\to0$ in different orders?  A double limit doesn't always exist.

Comment: No... We set $y=0$ and take the limit $x \to 0$ and then we also set $x=0$ and take the limit $y \to 0$.

Comment: @Evinda So pretty much a double limit, right?  (Use @ SimpleArt to get my attention)

Comment: Yes... @SimpleArt

Comment: @Evinda I've editted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are asking about a double limit's existence.

The following limits must be true for the original limit to exist:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}g(x,y)=\lim_{x\to0}\lim_{y\to0}g(x,y)=\lim_{y\to0}\lim_{x\to0}g(x,y)$$

If that doesn't hold true, then the double limit doesn't exist.

*-or-*

$$=\lim_{x\to0}g(x,0)=\lim_{y\to0}g(0,x)$$

Assuming $\lim_{x\to a}g(x,y)=g(a,y)$ and the function is continuous.

Comment: I edited my post. Could you take a look at it?

Comment: @Evinda Sure thing!

Comment: I see... nice.... Also by taking $g(x, mx)$ and showing that its limit depends on $m$ we show that the limit $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0) g(x,y)}$  does not exist, right? And if the limit of $g(x,y)$ is not a function of $m$, we don't know wether the limit $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} g(x,y)$ exists or not. Right?

Comment: @Evinda Actually, if we say that $m$ is a fixed constant, then the limit can exist as a function of $m$.

Comment: If we consider for example this limit $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sin{(2x)}-2x+y}{x^3+y}$ and pick $y=mx$ then we get that the limit is equal to $1$, but it does not exist. How can we justify this? @SimpleArt

Comment: @Evinda I would think to start with $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(2x)-2x}{x^3}$ and $\lim_{y\to0}\frac{y}{y}$, and if both approach $1$, then it seems to me as though the limit converges on $1$.  Since the limit as $x\to0$ doesn't equal the other limit, it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Evinda The problem is that you tried to connect $x$ and $y$ through $y=mx$.  When you do that, the limit exists **for that**.  However, the original limit broken up into $x$ and $y$ components doesn't exist because each individual limit fails to equal each other.

Comment: I have seen that it does does not exist. I was wondering if the limit would exist if the limits along the lines x=0 and y=0 would be equal...

Comment: @Evinda Then yes, if those limits are equal, the double limit should exist and be equal to that.

Answer (score 1):

A function can reach infinity in different ways depending on direction of approach, a simple example being  $y=cot(x)$  which tends to -$\inf$ at $x=0$ when approached from $x-$ and tends to +$\infty$ when approached from $x+$.

This is even more possible when considering a function of more than one variable.  Here the question is asking for the limit when approaching along the $y$ axis.

For $g(x)$ the limit ~ $(1/m)$ , found by substitution, so could be either 0 or infinite as $m$ varies; ie. limit varies with direction of approach, function is 'pathological' at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ oscillating wildly through all possible values of $u$.

The converse is true, if the limit is independent of $m$ the limit is stable and exists.

I have a feeling these concepts are easier to understand using Complex Variable Theory, which you may study later on; one of those cases when Advanced maths is easier than Elementary Maths.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your edit, $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} g(x, mx)$ can exist independently of $m$ even if $\lim\limits_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} g(x, y)$ does not exist. A simple example is
$$
g(x, y) = \begin{cases}
  1 & \text{if $y = x^{2}$,} \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
The limit of $g$ at the origin does not exist, but along *every* line through the origin, $g$ approaches $0$.

There are rational functions having analogous behavior, such as
$$
g(x, y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x^{2}y}{x^{4} + y^{2}} & (x, y) \neq (0, 0), \\
0 & (x, y) = (0, 0).
\end{cases}
$$
Here,
$$
g(x, mx) = \frac{mx^{3}}{x^{2}(x^{2} + m^{2})} \to 0\quad\text{as $x \to 0$, independently of $m$,}
$$
but $g(x, x^{2}) = \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x \neq 0$.

Comment: So by taking $g(x,mx)$ and showing that its limit depends on $m$ we show that the limit $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} g(x,y)$ but does not exist, right? And if the limit of $g(x,mx)$ is not a function of $m$, we don't know wether the limit  $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} g(x,y)$ exists or not. Right? @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: If we consider the limit along the line $x=0$ and the limit along the line $y=0$ and they are equal and have a value let $c$ does this mean that the original limit is equal to $c$?

Comment: "The limit of $g$ at the origin does not exist..."  I'm slightly confused at that, because the latter half of that sentence contradicts my understanding of what a limit is.

Comment: @Evinda: Your first comment is correct: If a function has two different limits along lines into the origin, the limit at the origin does not exist. Even if the limit along _every_ line exists and has the same value, however, you cannot deduce the function has a limit at the origin.

Comment: @SimpleArt: To say $g$ has a limit $L$ at the origin means, qualitatively, that $|g(x, y) - L|$ can be made as small as you like by taking $\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}$ sufficiently small. This is logically a stronger condition than saying $g$ has the same limit along every line (!), as both examples show: A "test particle" approaching the origin along the parabola $y = x^{2}$ "sees a different limit" than a particle approaching the origin along a line.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I have to admit, I am much weaker than I'd like to be with limits and calculus.  Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang That is such an amazing thought!  Wow!  Never knew that I could a) have a limit in '2-dimensions' (or variables) and b) have it approach the desired point in a non-linear path.  If you don't mind, what is the limit as it approaches along the parabola?

Comment: @SimpleArt: For the first function the limit is $1$; for the second it's $1/2$. (To see this, set $y = x^{2}$ in the corresponding formula and let $x \to 0$.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Oh, ok, got it.