# Limit of $\frac{\cos{x}-1-\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4+y^4}$ as it goes to the origin

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How can I solve a limit like this one:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{\cos{x}-1-\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4+y^4}$$

If I do $x=0$ so it aproaches through $y$ or $y=0$ so it approaches through $x$ it doesn't really help because of the division over $0$ in the denominator. As well as $x=y$, it doesn't make things better.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate post here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700997/geometrical-meaning-limits, found by [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B%5Ccos%7Bx%7D-1-%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E2%7D%7B2%7D%7D%7Bx%5E4%2By%5E4%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 1):

In this case we say that the limit does not exist (its value depends on the x, y path in $\mathbb{C}$).

Answer (score 0):

If $x = 0$ there is no division by zero ! Since when $x = 0$

$$f(x ,y) = \frac{\cos(x) - 1 -x^2/2}{x^4 + y^4} = \frac{1-1 - 0}{y^4} = 0$$

Therefore

$$ \lim_{y \to 0} f(0,y) = \lim_{y \to 0} 0 = 0.$$

If $y = 0$ then

$$ f(x,0) = \frac{\cos(x)-1-x^2/2}{x^4}.$$

Since the numerator and the denominator both converge to $0$ we can use L'Hospital's rule :

$$ \frac{- \sin x - x}{4x^3}$$

Since the numerator and denominator both converge to $0$ we use L'Hospital's rule a second time

$$ \frac{- \cos x - 1}{12x^2}$$

so we have 
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} f(x,0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-\cos(x)-1}{12x^2} = - \infty$$

Since the limit of $(x,y)$ to $(0,0)$ is different along two different paths the limit

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\cos(x)-1-x^2/2}{x^4 + y^4}$$
does not exist !